# Enabling GKE cluster Workload Identity in Terraform, receiving "Context Deadline exceeded"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a private GKE cluster with no public endpoint. I have confirmed that I can authenticate and run `kubectl` commands against the cluster with my principal account. I am deploying Terraform from the same VM I tested the `kubectl` commands against and have added that IP address to the cluster's Master Authorized Networks.

Whenever I try to deploy workload identity with Terraform, I receive this error:

```
Error: Post "https://10.0.0.2/api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts": context deadline exceeded

  on .terraform/modules/gke-workload-identity/modules/workload-identity/main.tf line 48, in resource "kubernetes_service_account" "main":
  48: resource "kubernetes_service_account" "main" {
```

I have granted the Service Account for Terraform deployment the proper IAM Roles for WI. I am using the standard `terraform-google-modules` for [workload identity](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest/submodules/workload-identity) and GKE [cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest/submodules/safer-cluster).

Here is also my TF Kubernetes provider block:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.gke.endpoint}"
  token                  = data.google_client_config.default.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.gke.ca_certificate)
}
```

Comment: I'd start by looking at `kubectl config view --raw` and ensure it is also using 10.0.0.2:443 (I'm accustomed to the apiserver being on :6443 but I haven't been in GKE in quite a while to speak to that)

Comment: @mdaniel that worked..for some reason terraform is outputting the private IP of the endpoint. I checked GCP Console and tested it with the endpoint listed there and it deployed successfully. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was something simple. Please [answer and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own solution, so you can let others know how to fix this, or just delete it if it was just a typo

Answer (score 1):

**Kubectl config view**

Displays merged kubeconfig settings or a specified kubeconfig file.

**Synopsis**

Displays merged kubeconfig settings or a specified kubeconfig file.

You can use –output jsonpath={…} to extract specific values using a jsonpath expression.

**Examples :**

```
kubectl config view --raw
```

For Community reference [kubectl_config_view](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_view/)